# why structural studies of the cerebellum (atrophy, segmentation, etc.) always reports LEFT and RIGHT even when laterality is absent from the study?

Tags: neuroscience, methodology, brain, neuroimaging, physiology

I have noticed that **structural** studies of the **cerebellum**, regardless of the focus of the study *(neurodegenerative, autism, alcoholism, drummers)* usually report left-sided and right-sided results. Even when the issue of laterality is absent from the study.

Is there anything particular about the cerebellum that is of good practice to report both sides?
when studying the structure, does this also happen with the cerebral cortex?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology & Neuroscience. It maybe because my general reasearch areas are not in the neuroscience half of this site, but this question is unclear to me. Could you please elaborate on what you are after? Maybe you could provide some example papers to clarify things too?

Comment: I agree with Chris - The brain is a bilateral structure, almost all structures have a mirror counterpart (some exceptions exist), so what are you exactly after? Implicitly you seem to say: '*scientific reports on the rest of the brain never lateralize their results*', which is most definitely not true; for instance generalized epilepsy versus partial epilepsy is explained mostly, if not totally by the recruitment of seizure activity of both hemispheres in generalized, but not partial/focal epilepsias.